React-native TypeError:Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
I'm using MACOS and making an app using vscode and react-native, but I keep getting errors saying: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined.
When I press the TouchableOpacity button, I want to go from the Start.tsx screen to the Logandsignin.tsx screen.
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { RootStackParamList } from '../../App';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

type StartScreenNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, 'Start'>;

type Props = {
  navigation: StartScreenNavigationProp;
};

const Start: React.FC<Props> = ({ navigation }) => {
  // 로깅을 추가하여 props가 어떻게 전달되는지 확인
  console.log('Received props:', navigation);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image
          source={require('../image/start.png')}
          style={styles.image}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.textContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Find</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Your</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text2}>Fit</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text2}>Pin</Text>
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => {
          if (navigation) {
            navigation.navigate('Logandsignin');
          } else {
            console.error('Navigation prop is undefined');
          }
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.buttontext}>시작하기</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  imageContainer: {
    flex: 3,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  image: {
    width: width,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
  textContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingLeft: width * 0.08,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: width * 0.08,
    color: '#9D9D9D',
  },
  text2: {
    fontSize: width * 0.08,
    color: '#000000',
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    padding: 16,
    margin: 20,
    marginLeft: 30,
    marginRight: 30,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  buttontext: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontSize: 24,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export default Start;


import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import Start from './src/Screens/Start';
import Logandsignin from './src/Screens/Logandsingin';

export type RootStackParamList = {
  Start: undefined;
  Logandsignin: undefined;
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Start">
        <Stack.Screen name="Start" component={Start} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Logandsignin" component={Logandsignin} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;

These are the versions I downloaded
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.29",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.73.6",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.16.2",
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.11.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.1",
"react-native-screens": "^3.31.1"
enter image description here
Can you tell me a solution. plz

Use StartScreenNavigationProp in place of Props like const Start: React.FC<StartScreenNavigationProp> and also check your navigation stack is right as per documentation.

Try to remove curly brackets. From:
const Start: React.FC<Props> = ({ navigation }) => {

To:
const Start: React.FC<Props> = (navigation) => {

And also change navigation.navigate() to navigation.navigation.navigate()
Only try!
